# VS Code shows red squiggles under "stdio.h" when workspace is in ~/src but not /tmp

Tags: c, macos, visual-studio-code, cmake, macos-catalina

Visual Studio Code shows red squiggles under `#include <stdio.h>` in the editor when the workspace is in `~/src` but not when it is in `/tmp`. Both workspaces compile and run the code fine. It's only an error in the editor.

I can reproduce this with a very simple `Hello World` C workspace. I am using CMake along with CMake Tools. Versions:

- macOS Catalina 10.15.7
- CMake 3.19.5
- Visual Studio Code 1.53.2
- C/C++ Extension 1.2.1
- CMake Tools Extension 1.6.0

Here's the directory structure:

```
% tree hello_world
hello_world
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── main.c
```

Here's `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(hello_world VERSION 1.0.0)

add_executable(hello_world main.c)
```

Here's `main.c`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the screenshot for `~/src`:

[image: src-workspace]

And here's the screenshot for `/tmp`:

[image: tmp-workspace]

**Edit**: Posted the output of "C/C++: Log Diagnostics" for both workspaces on a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/ddribin/541e85a4dc7f933b1a1862b58958952e). Here's part of the diff:

```
     Includes:
-        /usr/local/include
         /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include
-        /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include
         /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
-    Frameworks:
-        /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks
```

So this explains why it cannot find it in one workspace, but not why the paths are different.

Comment: Try running the "C/C++: Log Diagnostics" command from the command palette (Ctrl+Shift+P) in each workspace.  That should show which paths are being searched to find header files.  Perhaps add the resulting output to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**: This was [a bug](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/7014) in the VS Code C/C++ extension that was fixed in [version 1.2.2](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/releases/tag/1.2.2).

---

This is apparently an [FAQ](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/faq-cpp#_why-do-i-see-red-squiggles-under-standard-library-types):

> Q: Why do I see red squiggles under Standard Library types?
>
> A: The most common reason for this is missing include paths and defines. The easiest way to fix this on each platform is as follows:
>
> **Linux/Mac**: Set `"intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"` or `"intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"` and `compilerPath` in `c_cpp_properties.json` to the path to your compiler.

I changed only `intelliSenseMode` to `clang-x64` (it was unset), leaving `compilerPath` alone, and that fixed the problem. I don't understand why the source directory causes "missing include paths" or why this mode is not the default, but it works now.

**Edit**: I created [issue #7014](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/7014) on the `microsoft/vscode-cpptools` GitHub project.

**Edit**: My issue was duped to [issue #6992](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/6992), which has been fixed in [version 1.2.2](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/releases/tag/1.2.2).

[image: intelliSenseMode]